# How to efficiently select some data from a large trajectory set

Tags: python, pandas

**The situation**

I have one dataframe with one (well actually three but let's start with one) set of coordinates (X,Y) or **trajectory** (in two columns). For the sake to illustrate my point and to have some reproducible example let's use this code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create data for trajectories
n_points = 500
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_points)
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [10 * np.cos(theta) for theta in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_points)],
    'Y': [10 * np.sin(theta) for theta in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_points)],
    'XL': [11 * np.cos(theta) for theta in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_points)],
    'YL': [11 * np.sin(theta) for theta in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_points)],
    'XR': [9 * np.cos(theta) for theta in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_points)],
    'YR': [9 * np.sin(theta) for theta in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_points)]
})


fig = go.Figure()

# Add traces for trajectories
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['X'], y=data['Y'], mode='lines+markers', name='Circle 1', line=dict(color='blue')))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['XL'], y=data['YL'], mode='lines+markers', name='Circle 2', line=dict(color='red')))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['XR'], y=data['YR'], mode='lines+markers', name='Circle 3', line=dict(color='green')))

# Define the rectangle parameters
XC, YC = 7.07, 7.07  # Center of the rectangle
XD, YD = 1, -1  # Direction of the rectangle
width = 3
height = 4

# Calculate the corner points of the rectangle using trigonometric functions
theta = np.arctan2(YD, XD)
cos_theta = np.cos(theta)
sin_theta = np.sin(theta)

rectangle_x = [XC + 0.5 * width * cos_theta - 0.5 * height * sin_theta,
               XC - 0.5 * width * cos_theta - 0.5 * height * sin_theta,
               XC - 0.5 * width * cos_theta + 0.5 * height * sin_theta,
               XC + 0.5 * width * cos_theta + 0.5 * height * sin_theta,
               XC + 0.5 * width * cos_theta - 0.5 * height * sin_theta]

rectangle_y = [YC + 0.5 * width * sin_theta + 0.5 * height * cos_theta,
               YC - 0.5 * width * sin_theta + 0.5 * height * cos_theta,
               YC - 0.5 * width * sin_theta - 0.5 * height * cos_theta,
               YC + 0.5 * width * sin_theta - 0.5 * height * cos_theta,
               YC + 0.5 * width * sin_theta + 0.5 * height * cos_theta]

# Add a trace for the rectangle
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=rectangle_x, y=rectangle_y, fill='toself',  name='Rectangle'))

# Customize layout
fig.update_layout(
    title='Trajectories and Rectangle Plot',
    xaxis_title='X-axis',
    yaxis_title='Y-axis',
    showlegend=True
)
# Set axis aspect ratio to ensure circles appear as circles
fig.update_xaxes(scaleanchor="y", scaleratio=1)
fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor="x", scaleratio=1)

fig.show()
```

This give us

[image]

Take into account that for the example I put a perfect circular trajectory but this can be anything, as long as it is continuous.

**What I want**

As you can see in the plot there is a rectangle. This rectangle is centered at a point in the X,Y trajectory. (XC,YC).

What I want is to get **only** the data (I am not sure in what format, perhaps a sub dataframe??) that is contained inside the rectangle.   (and let's say plot it for confirmation)

I realize that I can make a comparation of all the data that I have to check if it is inside the rectangle but here I have 500 points and I expect to have many more in the trajectory I am thinking (50,000 points). And I believe checking all of them might take too much time

Is there a way to efficiently select some geographical region (the rectangle) from the original data?

*(after note)*
After selecting the data I would like to coordinate transform this so that I can plot it in coordinates where XC,YC is the origin and the rectangle sides are parallel to X,Y. But first I need the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible way is to change the frame to (XC, YC) using a translation and apply a rotation of theta to all points. All operations are vectorized:

```
def isin(X, Y):
    X = X - XC
    Y = Y - YC
    X_ = X*cos_theta + Y*sin_theta
    Y_ = -X*sin_theta + Y*cos_theta
    return (-width/2 <= X_) & (X_ <= width/2) & (-height/2 <= Y_) & (Y_ <= height/2)

m1 = isin(data['X'], data['Y'])
m2 = isin(data['XL'], data['YL'])
m3 = isin(data['XR'], data['YR'])
```

Output:

```
>>> m1.sum(), m2.sum(), m3.sum()
(24, 22, 26)
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(data.loc[m1, 'X'], data.loc[m1, 'Y'], c='b')
plt.scatter(data.loc[m2, 'XL'], data.loc[m2, 'YL'], c='r')
plt.scatter(data.loc[m3, 'XR'], data.loc[m3, 'YR'], c='g')
plt.plot(rectangle_x, rectangle_y, c='k')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start by defining a bounding box aligned with the original coordinate set [x_left, x1_right, y_top, y_bottom] and filter out all data points outside of this (with pandas index slicing it should be quite efficient).

Then you have no option but to check whether the remaining points are actually inside the real rectangle, then the fastest way might be to rotate the coordinate set so that the rectangle is aligned with the new coordinate set, and use index slicing again to get the final set of coordinates. And that should give you what you want.